# how $\sqrt x \sqrt{1+\epsilon} \approx \sqrt x \left( 1+\frac{\epsilon}{2} +O(\epsilon ^2) \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I am looking for some explanation of how the following was completed.
$$\sqrt{x(1+\epsilon)}= \sqrt x \sqrt{1+\epsilon}\approx \sqrt x \left( 1+\frac{\epsilon}{2} +O(\epsilon ^2) \right)$$

I understand $$\sqrt{x(1+\epsilon)}= \sqrt x \sqrt{1+\epsilon}$$

but I am confused how $$\sqrt x \sqrt{1+\epsilon} \approx \sqrt x \left( 1+\frac{\epsilon}{2} +O(\epsilon ^2) \right)$$

the above uses the taylor series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also simply add a small quantity to get a complete square
$$
\sqrt{1+ϵ}\approx\sqrt{1+ϵ+\frac{ϵ^2}4}=1+\fracϵ2.
$$
To check the difference, use the binomial formula $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ in
$$
\sqrt{1+ϵ}-(1+\fracϵ2)=\frac{(1+ϵ)-(1+ϵ+\frac{ϵ^2}4)}{\sqrt{1+ϵ}+(1+\fracϵ2)}\approx-\frac{ϵ^2}8.
$$

Comment: how do you know what small quantity to add?

Comment: You want to get a complete square $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ by adding terms that are small against $ϵ$. The most simple variant is to identify $a=1$ and $2b=ϵ$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the formula of the asymptotic expansion of the function : $x \mapsto \sqrt{1+x}$ near $0$.

The taylor serie  of $x \mapsto \sqrt{1+x}$ is: 
$$(\forall \mid x \mid < 1), \sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \binom{1/2}{k}x^k $$

But note that we have :

$$\sum_{k = n}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{k}x^k = O_{x \to 0} (x^n)$$

Hence an asymptotic expansion of $x \mapsto \sqrt{1+x}$ at the order $n$ is : 
$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n \binom{1/2}{k}x^k + O(x^n)$$

in your case it's just the asymptotic expansion of order $2$ (so $n = 2$ in the above formula).

Comment: doesn't it use the taylor series?

Comment: It does use the Taylor series.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation could you add more detail?

Comment: how does it use big 0?

Comment: I added an explanation.